# Cheese is crashing when taking video in Saucy

Tags: 13.10, cheese

It happened in 12.10 and the problem has returned. Using version 3.8.3 from Software Centre. How to fix it?

Comment: It also happened in 13.10.
But, then works fine in 14.04.

Comment: @RishirajSurti Does not even work for me in 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Use `guvcview` instead. Cheese has always been broken/horridly slow for me.

Comment: Guvcview also produces black video. It seems that Ubuntu 13.10 is not for me.

Comment: Are you using open source or proprietary drivers? AMD, Intel, or NVIDIA?

Comment: I only have Intel Pentium dual core processor with a little integrated graphics and nothing else. According to "About this computer" the driver is `Intel® G33 x86/MMX/SSE2` and experience is Standard.

Comment: Might want to try the oibaf PPA. `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers; sudo sed -i 's/saucy/raring/g' etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf*; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y; sudo reboot` for the latest Intel drivers, which may have fixed the issue you are having.

Comment: Then again, I saw your issues earlier and you've already tried this. All I can say is, stick with Ubuntu 13.04 if it worked fine. You can always try Ubuntu 14.04 later, but you may want to look into getting newer hardware.